# Cordova Background Geolocation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, http-headers, http-post, ionic3

I need help in this plugin
[Ionic Background Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/)
. In this plugin we can set URL where we can send the updated location. Now I'm confused how to do that. Right now I have website let say http://apps.tracker.com, I'm sending data like http://apps.tracker.com?user=abc&lat=27.1221&long=70.23123 but I don't know how to integrate the link with this plugin.

Comment: Are you using php ?

Comment: No sir we are not using php.

Answer (score 0):

See my Github project:

- [mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server](https://github.com/oliviercherrier/mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server): REST API for storing locations provided by mauron85-background-geolocation plugin
- [mauron85-background-geolocation-example-ionic2](https://github.com/oliviercherrier/mauron85-background-geolocation-example-ionic2): Demonstration application which communicate with  mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server.

Hope it could help.